# Saving as a .tex file, not .bak

Tags: editors, winedt

I have existing .tex file and want to create similar one. I am doing this by saving the file with another name, I just click "save as", but it won't be saved as a .tex file. Instead it creates .bak file or something else that cannot be compiled any more. What is the problem and what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, welcome. Which editor are you using? It's not just saving a `.bak` (which is intended as a backup file) in addition to the `.tex` file?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I use WinEdt 8.1. It wasn't problem before, I just want copy with another name file.

Comment: I don't use WinEdt, so I'm afraid I can't say what it might be doing. Another option is of course to open the folder containing the `.tex` file, and make a copy of it there, instead of saving a new file in WinEdt. Or make a new empty file in WinEdt, and copy-paste the content from your first file.

Comment: Thank you very much Torbjorn.  Copy-paste just might work. I'll try this now.

Comment: I'm using WinEdt 10.1, and I haven't such problems. Try updating.

Comment: I don't use Windows if I can avoid it, but I seem to remember that it usually 'hides' the file extension of file types it (thinks it) knows. Might this be happening in part because you do not have direct control over the *whole* file name?

Comment: This is not the default behavior in any version of WinEdt. Check, when you "Save As", that the default "Save As" filter is "TeX".